# Should I put a surge protector on the 110v to my Trane furnace

Tags: hvac, surge-suppression

I just had to swap out the fan control module for my Trane furnace.  The service person said it might have failed due to spikes on the 110v line.  There were downed power lines in the area within the past 24 hrs due to a winter storm.  Perhaps there were some associated spikes.  Should I put a surge protector on the 110v line to the furnace?  (Or was the tech just wrong?)

Comment: the tech was not wrong ... i lost a furnace control board and a playstation when a lightning hit nearby

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a whole house surge suppressor. They can be attached to your existing panel. If you have extra space in the panel and depending on the type of panel, you can get them that plug right into 2 side by side poles. Otherwise they can be attached to a double pole breaker. They come in various types and protection ratings. Of course the greater the protection, the greater the price.

With as much electronic devices and coprocessors that are now in a residence. It doesn't hurt to have a little protection that could save you thousands of dollars. Even if you house is insured, consider the deductible and the hassle of replacing everything after a major surge and damage.

Good luck.

Comment: This IEEE presentation gives some useful background (https://www.ieee-sfv.org/app/download/9493392/IEEE+Surge+Protection+Presentation.pdf). A typical residence would be looking for a "Type 2" surge suppressor installed on the load side of your meter as RME indicated. A quality unit (e.g., EATON CHSPT2ULTRA) can be had for $100-$150. It's an easy DIY install as long as you are  comfortable working safely inside your service panel.

Comment: Thumbs up on the whole house surge protector,  They are not expensive, work great, and are easy to install.